# How to make Vaadin Crud Editor window remain on screen once save is clicked?

Tags: java, vaadin, crud

I created vaadin crud component and its editor. When user clicks the row, editor opens automatically. Then if user makes change and clicks save, editor window closes automatically. Everything is fine until now, but if user makes some wrong changes, I'm showing vaadins warning message and editor still closes automatically. I just want to make crud editor remain on screen only if warning message created.

I couldn't find any solution on vaadin's documentation. By the way, I have created my own enhanced crud object which extends crud object.
My crud's save listener runs a method and the method doesn't return any value. Editor always closes once the below method is run.

My vaadin version: 14

```
private BinderCrudEditor<Account> createEditor() {
    TextField nameField = new TextField("Test textfield");
    nameField.setWidth("300px");
    Checkbox disableField = new Checkbox("Disable");
    carrierDragDrop = new CarrierDragDrop(getParameters());
    carrierDragDrop.setReadOnly(isReadOnly());

    Binder<Account> binder = new Binder<>(Account.class);
    binder.forField(nameField).asRequired("message1").withValidator(this::validateForSameNameCarrier, "message2")
            .withValidator(this::validateForSameNameRoutingClass, "message3")
            .withValidator(this::validateForSameNameAccounts, "message4").bind(Account::getName, Account::setName);
    binder.forField(disableField).bind(account -> !account.isActive(), (account, disable) -> account.setActive(!disable));
    carrierDragDrop.setValueChangeListener(event -> {
        if (event.isFromClient()) {
            crud.setDirty(true);
        }
    });

    MixedVerticalLayout layout = new MixedVerticalLayout();
    layout.getRoot(false).add(nameField, carrierDragDrop, disableField);
    return new BinderCrudEditor<>(binder, layout);
}
```

Comment: Please provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you using Binder to validate the form? If so, the saving should not be possible if there is a validation error.

Comment: I've added my createEditor method which includes binder. I want to show a warning message if carrierDragDrop has no value. carrierDragDrop is a custom-made class and I'm checking its value in crud's saveListener.